# TFS SqlExecute Custom Activity

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I use [`SqlExecute` activity of Build Extension](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CustomActivities/MAIN/Source/Activities/SqlServer/SqlExecute.cs)

I wish pass params in arguments of my activity

But my problem is Te parameters are not injected into the SQL script, can you help me please. have you used SqlExecute activity?

Parameters Section in editor, in my build designer of template tfs / wwf :

```
New String(5) {
    "BackupFilePath = F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\DUMP\ClearProdDump\CP.dmp",
    "LogicalDataFile = CP_Data01",
    "DataFilePath = F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\data\",
    "LogicalLogFile = CP_TLog01",
    "LogFilePath = F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\log\",
    "DatabaseName = AghilasCP_Tmp"
}
```

My Script.sql

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = $(DatabaseName ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the code of that activity it seems that you need to specify the parameters as

```
New String(5) {
    "@BackupFilePath='F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\DUMP\ClearProdDump\CP.dmp'",
    "@LogicalDataFile='CP_Data01'",
    "@DataFilePath='F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\data\'",
    "@LogicalLogFile='CP_TLog01'",
    "@LogFilePath='F:\MSSQL10.IS_CLTLIVE_DE\log\'",
    "@DatabaseName='AghilasCP_Tmp'"
}
```

And the statement as

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DatabaseName)
```

With no spaces around the '=', with a unique name as a parameter name, this scares me a bit, I'd personally have written built this activity differently, and with quotes around the parameter value either in the parameter array or in the SQL code.

Comment: Thank you very much jesse, i edited in order rename parameters for security

Comment: Error: Tools\TeamBuild\RestoreDatabaseForTesting.sql. Must declare the scalar variable "@DatabaseName".. Stack Trace:    at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.SqlServer.SqlExecute.ExecuteFiles()
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.SqlServer.SqlExecute.ExecuteSql()
   at TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.BaseCodeActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context). Inner Exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@DatabaseName".

Comment: Try raising the Build Logging to verbose, the actual statements being executed should be logged to the Build log. I'm not inclined to install and debug the activity myself.

Comment: I just extracted the code that substitutes the parameters and create a small test for it, the parameters above should work with the statement above. If they don't then there must be something you're not telling us.

Comment: thank you jesse i resolved my problem , i forgot simple quotte on parameter, i edited your answer in order to add simple quote